# MySQL - where clause on triple nested select

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing the most complicated query I've personally ever done... and I'm stuck!

Here's the code:

```
SELECT 
    el.UID, 
    (
        SELECT 
            SUM(booked)  
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT 
                ts.*, max(ts.dateStored) 
                FROM eventsDetails ed 
                JOIN ticketSales ts ON ts.DUID = ed.UID 
                WHERE ed.event_masterEvent = 1147 
                GROUP BY ts.DUID
            ) a 
    ) as booked,
    el.event_confirmed, 
    el.event_title, 
    (
        SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(g.colour) 
        FROM eventsGenre eg 
        JOIN genres g ON g.UID = eg.GUID 
        WHERE eg.EUID = el.UID
    ) AS genreCodes, 
    (
        SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(g.genre) 
        FROM eventsGenre eg 
        JOIN genres g ON g.UID = eg.GUID 
        WHERE eg.EUID = el.UID
    ) AS genreNames 
FROM eventsList el 
JOIN eventsDetails ed ON el.UID = ed.event_masterEvent 
WHERE el.event_active='1' 
AND ed.event_eventDateAndTime >= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY el.UID 
ORDER BY ed.event_eventDateAndTime ASC
```

On the line "WHERE ed.event_masterEvent = 1147", I wan't to change that to "WHERE ed.event_masterEvent = el.UID". 1147 was just to test that the code works... but now I need to reference the overall event ID.

Whenever I do that, I get an error saying the column doesn't exist.

I don't understand, because further down the query, I am able to say "WHERE eg.EUID = el.UID" within a sub select.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong... as I said before, I'm very much out of my comfort zone at the moment and looking for some MySQL gurus to ride in and explain where I've gone wrong.

I've got a feeling I need to add another join somewhere, but I can't work out where. I tried to search for the answer, but I'm not really sure what search terms to use - so I'm not getting very far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a fiddle of the issue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c77a98/2

Comment: I don't understand why you need that nested `SELECT`. What's the point of the unused `MAX(ts.dateStored)`?

Comment: If you're trying to get the `booked` value on the last `ts.dateStored` for each `DUID`, that's not the correct way. See [row with max value of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1)

Comment: As I said - I'm new to this... so thank you for the advice. I will go and take a look. However, is there a reason that I can't reference el.UID from the nested select - or is there a way to do that?

Comment: From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html): Derived tables (subqueries in a FROM clause of a SELECT) can't contain outer references or references to other tables of the same SELECT

Comment: Is there a 1:1 correspondence between ed.UID and ed.event_masterEvent?

Comment: no... there is a 1:1 correspondence between el.UID and ed.event_masterEvent - is that what you meant?

Comment: No, was hoping there was as it would make it possible to simplify the derived query. I think you are going to need a JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you posted is grossly overcomplicated, and can be made significantly more readable if you use some `JOIN`s.

I've managed to rewrite (untested) most of your query, as follows, but I am unsure about refactoring the `booked` portion, because it's not clear what you're trying to achieve without having a solid schema and sample data to reference.

If you'd care to create a working SQL fiddle with your schema and data, I'll have a stab at finishing it. If not, hopefully the following might help you to simplify and solve your problem.

```
SELECT 
    el.UID,
    el.event_confirmed, 
    el.event_title, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.genre SEPARATOR ', ') AS genreNames,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.colour SEPARATOR ', ') AS genreCodes,
    SUM(ts.booked) AS booked
FROM eventsList el
INNER JOIN eventsDetails ed ON (el.UID = ed.event_masterEvent AND ed.event_eventDateAndTime >= CURDATE())
LEFT JOIN eventsGenre eg ON (el.UID = eg.EUID)
LEFT JOIN genres g ON (eg.GUID = g.UID)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ts.*, MAX(ts.dateStored)
    FROM eventsDetails ed 
    INNER JOIN ticketSales ts ON ts.DUID = ed.UID 
    GROUP BY ts.DUID
) AS ts ON (ed.UID = ts.DUID)
WHERE el.event_active = 1
AND el.UID = 1147
GROUP BY el.UID
ORDER BY ed.event_eventDateAndTime ASC;
```

Comment: You should probably use `DISTINCT` in the `GROUP_CONCAT`s, otherwise you'll get duplication because of the additional join. But this answer doesn't address the real problem in his query, which is how to get the `booked` values that he wants.

Comment: Good call on the `DISTINCT`. I realise it doesn't answer his question right now, but the query he posted is a mess, so I've tried to simplify it, and with some more information from OP I can answer his question too. But as I said in my answer, he can take it or leave it.

Comment: I've never created a fiddle before... I'm just checking it out now. I don't doubt that the query is over complicated... but, I'm trying to get better :)

Comment: I think you need to join with a subquery that gets `SUM(booked) ... GROUP BY event_masteruid, DUID`, and join on `el.UID = DUID`.

Comment: As the `MAX(ts.dateStored)` isn't used, I was thinking to just `LEFT JOIN ticketSales ts ON (ed.UID = ts.DUID)`, and to `SUM(ts.booked) AS booked`, as the `GROUP BY el.UID` should handle the aggregation.

Comment: @BlindTrevor - I have updated my query. It now gives the same result as the query in your SQL fiddle, but without the need for `WHERE ed.event_masterEvent = 1147` on the sub query. Is this what you needed?

Comment: @fubar - you're a flipping genius! Thank you so much. I will pick this apart and learn from it... but it's working perfectly!